# Youtube埋め込み動画の再生タイミング制御について

Tags: javascript, youtube-player-api, youtube

初めまして。
動画の再生タイミングを制御する方法についてお聞かせして欲しいです。

現在youtube埋め込み動画をYoutube Iframe APIを用いて再生させているのですが、
現状autoplayであるためにページの読み込みと同時に再生されてしまい、
視聴者が動画の位置にたどり着いた時には再生途中であるという状態です。

視聴者が動画の位置についてたどり着いた時に再生するためのコードを教えていただきたいです。

おそらくjavascriptを用いてseekedされた時にイベントが発生するというような内容になるのかなと思っております。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview は、どうでしょう？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtubeのiframe windowへ　postMessageでコマンド（メッセージ）を送れば制御できます。
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=ja#playVideo 
以下、簡易なサンプルです。（developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_referenceのコードを使いました。）

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<div style="height: 1000px;width: 100%">1</div>
<div style="height: 1000px;width: 100%">2</div>
<!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
<div style="height: 1000px;width: 100%">3<div id="player"></div></div>
<div style="height: 1000px;width: 100%">4</div>
<div style="height: 1000px;width: 100%">5</div>

<script>
    // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
    //    after the API code downloads.
    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '360',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        //event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
    //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
    //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
    var done = false;
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
            setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
            done = true;
        }
    }
    function stopVideo() {
       // player.stopVideo();
    }

    function actions(action){
        //pw = $('#player')[0].contentWindow;
        pw = document.getElementById('player').contentWindow;
        pw.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"'+action+'","args":""}', '*');
    }

    process_f = false;

    window.addEventListener( "scroll", function(){
        var y = window.pageYOffset;
        var h = window.innerHeight;
        var element = document.getElementById('player');
        var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        var point_a = rect.top+y

        p1 = point_a-(h)-rect.height;
        p2 = point_a+(h)-rect.height;
        if(!(p1 > y) && !(p2 < y)){
            if(!process_f){
//                player.playVideo();
                actions('playVideo');
            }
            process_f = true;
        }else{
            if(process_f) {
//                player.stopVideo();
                actions('stopVideo');
            }
            process_f = false;
        }
    }) ;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: こちらの言葉足らずで失礼しました。
今回考えているのは”自動再生”のタイミングを制御するというものです。
すなわち、ユーザーがその動画の位置についてときに自動的に動画が再生されるような制御は難しいでしょうか？
自動再生については問題なくできますが、ページの読み込みと同時に自動再生が行われます。

Comment: 色々な実現方法を検討していただければと、サンプルスクリプトを更新しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
こちらで試してみたところ考えていたような再生タイミングの制御ができました。